# If disabling macro on excel file you can not copy a sheet from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am using this function to copy a sheet from a Workbook to another Workbook.
 I works, but it seems that if I disable the macros from Workbook, 
 it can not copy the sheet anymore.

If I chage this line :   `m_objExcel.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`

to this  `m_objExcel.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI`

it works but gets a warning message.
Also if I comment the line it works perfectly but with macros On.

```
Private Sub CopyFunction() 
    Set m_objExcel = New Excel.Application 'creare obiect
    m_objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 

    g_secAutomation = m_objExcel.AutomationSecurity
    m_objExcel.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    m_objExcel.Visible = True


    Dim CopyFrom As Workbook
    Dim CopyTo As Workbook
    Dim CopyThis As Object

    Set CopyFrom = m_objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\FromFile.xls")
    Set CopyTo = m_objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\ToFile.xls")

      Set CopyThis = CopyFrom.Sheets(1) ''Sheet number 1
      CopyThis.Copy After:=CopyTo.Sheets(1)

    m_objExcel.Workbooks(CopyTo.FullName).Save
    CopyFrom.Close
    CopyTo.Close
    m_objExcel.Workbooks.Close
    MsgBox "ok"
    End Sub
```

I am using it from Access and work with a Excel file.
What is the problem? 
Is there a way to still be able to copy a sheet from a workbook to another, and have the macros disabled?

Comment: When you disable macros, you cannot execute VBA so your code wouldn't even get executed. This may seem pretty obvious so I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I am using it from Access and work with a Excel file. The macro disable is on to Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is here:

```
 m_objExcel.Workbooks(CopyTo.Name).Save
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what the disable macro is typically for: Security.
It is meant for your own protection; in case you receive a workbook from an unknown author, this person may want to send you harmful software.
Imagine for example that code starts deleting files as soon as you open the workbook.
Disabling macro's prevents this and allows you to look into code before you decide to execute it.

As a solution, the user can trust you as author while you sign your project as developer.
I suggest that you check out this link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa190098(v=office.10)

(You can decide to turn off the security entirely (Enable macro's), but this is generally not recommended.)

Comment: Is there a way to still be able to copy a sheet from a workbook to another, and have the macros disabled?

Comment: I don't think you should try to control the security settings of your users. Even though there could be sophisticated ways to bypass the macro security, I probably wouldn't propagate it. But you can use the option I suggested, to use signed projects; this allows you to keep security level high while not being bothered by the notifications.